# Guidance for a surface integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, surfaces, surface-integrals

I've been dealing with a problem of surface integrals, I hope you could give me an advice.

I have this parameterized function $G = (r\cos\theta, r\cos\theta, r)$ with $0\le r \le 1$ and $0\le\theta\le2\pi$. I have to find a formula for the surface area of this parameterized function.

I started derivating $G$ so $$G_r = (\cos\theta, 2\sin\theta,1)$$ $$G_\theta = (-r\sin\theta, 2r\cos\theta, 0)$$
$$||G_r\times G_\theta|| = \sqrt{4r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta+4r^2} = \sqrt{r^2(3\cos^2\theta+5)}=r\sqrt{3\cos^2\theta + 5}$$ 
Now I tried to do the integral with the given integral limits of $r$ and $\theta$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}r\sqrt{3\cos^2\theta+5}drd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\cfrac{\sqrt{3\cos^2\theta+5}}{2}d\theta$$

I saw that the solution had to do with a complete elliptic integral, but I would hope you could guide me if there is another way to do that integral and also if I'm doing any procedure wrong.

Comment: You have typo(s) either in the definition of $g$ (which then became $T$ suddenly) or in the computation of the partial derivatives of $g$.

Comment: A factor of $2$ appears in the middle component of both derivatives.  If $G$ is correct, the $2$ shouldn't be there.  It's the cause of your elliptic integral.